# Compounding words for Solr indexing

Tags: java, indexing, filter, solr, lucene

Is There a filter or a tokenizer that applies the composition of words to an input?
For instance, if I have "Hello Guys How are you?", it must to indexes in this way as well: "HelloGuys", "GuysHow", "Howare", "areyou" and when I search terms "HelloGuys" it must find the docs with that field value. I thought that WordDelimiterGraphFilter is the right filter, but it divides compound words, it doesn't make compound words. I'm looking for something like that, opposite WordDelimiterGraphFilter, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're looking for is called shingles. Solr has a [ShingleFilter](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/filter-descriptions.html#FilterDescriptions-ShingleFilter) which joins tokens together as they appear in the token stream. You can adjust how many tokens you want to join together (i.e. `HelloGuysHow`) if that's what you're looking for, and change the delimiter between the tokens (i.e. `Hello_Guys`) if you want to.

> ```
> <analyzer>
>   <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
>   <filter class="solr.ShingleFilterFactory"/>
> </analyzer>
> ```
>
> In: "To be, or what?"
>
> Tokenizer to Filter: "To"(1), "be"(2), "or"(3), "what"(4)
>
> Out: "To"(1), "To be"(1), "be"(2), "be or"(2), "or"(3), "or what"(3), "what"(4)

For your use case, use `tokenSeparator=""`.

Comment: It's great. Thanks very much for your help :).
PS: Without using a tokenSeparator, it is needs to enter additionally a filter for remove whitespace from tokens.

Comment: Sorry, I've again question. Is there a way for set up the minShingleSize as the number of the words of token stream?
I want to get that the filter to join from two to all the words of the token stream.

Comment: The `minShingleSize` would be set to 2 in that case, while you can set the `maxShingleSize` to a large value to make it combine every term after it in the token stream. The example on the shingle filter documentation page shows it for `maxShingleSize` set to 4.

Comment: So if I don't know the number of words, I have to set up maxShingleSize to 10000 and I'm sure that it shingles all chain words. it's right?

Comment: Correct, it's set to 2 by default  if you don't give a value.

Comment: I entered 1000 for maxShingleSize and the indexing is failed and it give me this exception:
`de.hybris.platform.solrfacetsearch.indexer.exceptions.IndexerException: de.hybris.platform.solrfacetsearch.indexer.exceptions.IndexerException: Indexer worker failed. Max number of retries in total has been reached` :(

Comment: I'm not familiar with Hybris at all. Try a smaller number and check the actual Solr log and not the indexer log. Lucene has a max size for a single token of 32768 bytes, so if you're exceeding that it's going to fail.

Comment: However, your answer was a great help.